# What do brackets do in an interface declaration

Tags: objective-c, interface

I stumbled upon https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/blob/master/Extensions/NSObject%2BProperties.h

The interface is defined as:

```
@interface NSObject (AQProperties)
```

What does the `(AQProperties)` part do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a "category". You can extend existing classes, even if you do not have the source code for them, by adding your methods to a named category:

```
@interface NSString (MyFancyStuff)
- (NSString*) stringByCopyingStringAndReplacingDollarCharsWithEuros;
- (NSUInteger) lengthIgnoringWhitespace;
@end
```

You can then implement these new methods as usual

```
@implementation NSString (MyFancyStuff)
- (NSString*) stringByCopyingStringAndReplacingDollarCharsWithEuros
{
    ...
}

- (NSUInteger) lengthIgnoringWhitespace 
{
    ...
}
@end
```

These new methods then behave like all other methods of `NSString` (provided, you did include the header file, where you declared the category):

```
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello, %@", param];
NSUInteger length = [text lengthIgnoringWhitespace];

...
```

Apart from being a tool to extend classes, whose code you don't have, categories can also be useful to structure the interfaces of your own classes. For example:

FancyStuff.h

```
@interface FancyStuff 
// Public methods and properties are declared here
@end
```

FancyStuff+Protected.h

```
#import "FancyStuff.h"

@interface FancyStuff (Protected)
// Methods, which may be useful for classes, which derive from 
// FancyStuff, but should not be considered part of the public API
@end
```

FancyStuff.m

```
#import "FancyStuff+Protected.h"

@implementation FancyStuff
...
@end

@implementation FancyStuff (Protected)
...
@end
```

Comment: OK. I then declare an interface of the sort: 
#import "NSObject+Properties.h"
@interface GFDictionaryInitiable : NSObject

But when I try to access a method defined in my Category, I get the following: 

-[GFRestaurant hasPropertyNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. GFRestaurant is an instance of GFDictionaryInitiable. 

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `GFRestaurant` an **instance** of `GFDictionaryInitiable` or a **subclass**? Reading the error message, `GFRestaurant` seems to be a subclass.

Comment: A subclass: @interface GFRestaurant : GFDictionaryInitiable

Comment: Could you provide more context? Show some code?

Comment: I have a first class, @interface GFDictionaryInitiable : NSObject. I want all subclasses of GFDictionaryInitiable, such as GFRestaurant (@interface GFRestaurant : GFDictionaryInitiable) to also have all methods impletemented in NSObject+Properties.h

Comment: Show us some code... Besides, since `GFDicitionaryInitable` inherits from `NSObject`, it should inherit the methods in categories on `NSObject`, too. Just to make sure: is the file implementing `NSObject (Properties)` part of your Xcode project, and properly linked into the executable?

Comment: Creating a new question, with proper code examples. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432324/objective-c-how-to-inherit-category-methods-defined-in-a-parent-class

Answer (score 1):

They are [categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2) - a great way to extend existing classes without subclassing them.

To sum up, your `NSObject (AQProperties)` defines an `NSObject` with some extra methods that pertains to `AQProperties`.

Unlike a subclass, you can only add methods to a category, not an extra data member.