# Objective C: how to inherit category methods loaded in a parent class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, objective-c-category

In my project, I am using the `NSObject+Properties.h` category (see aqtoolkit: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/blob/master/Extensions/NSObject%2BProperties.h)

I then have a class that I declare as

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSObject+Properties.h"

@interface GFDictionaryInitiable : NSObject
...
```

I then have several subclasses of `GFDictionaryInitiable`, such as `GFRestaurant`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "GFDictionaryInitiable.h"

@interface GFRestaurant : GFDictionaryInitiable
...
```

My problem is that I cannot access methods defined in the `NSObject+Properties` category in my subclasses. For example I get the error:

```
-[GFRestaurant hasPropertyNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2e57240
```

How can I have all my subclasses 'inherit' the category's methods that are loaded in the parent class?

Comment: Are you sure that "NSObject+Properties.m" has been added to your target?

Comment: It should work. Are you sure your .m file is included in your target? Go to `Build Phases > Compiled Sources` and see if the `NSObject+Properties.m` is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you get a *runtime exception*, and not a compiler error, I assume that you forgot
to add "NSObject+Properties.m" to your target. Select the file and check the
"Target Membership" checkbox in the File inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
#import "NSObject+Properties.h"
```

to your sub classes .h files.

Comment: He isn't having trouble compiling, so I don't believe this will fix his issue.

Comment: Yes.  Probably Martin's answer is the correct one - but just in case he's misreporting a compiler warning.